# Turning off shadow property generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, entity-framework-core

I'm having a weird issue with setting Entity Framework Core foreign keys. EF keeps adding a shadow property automatically for my property and is creating a foreign key of it.

That would be perfectly fine for me, however - I want to be able to set the foreign key delete behaviour to cascade - using that "automatic" shadow property I'm not allowed to do that.

Therefore I decided to create my own foreign key with the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PostDataModel>(e =>
{
    // Primary key
    e.HasKey(c => c.Id);

    // Relation
    e.HasOne<PostGroupDataModel>()
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("GroupId")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();
});
```

This however, did not help much - automatically generated shadow property is still being generated for the table (`GroupId1`):

[image]

```
public class PostGroupDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Params { get; set; }

    public List<PostDataModel> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class PostDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public PostGroupDataModel Group { get; set; }
}
```

**Is there a way to turn off automatic generation of the shadow property in EF Core?** or at least modify the generated shadow property to delete on cascade?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just add a `public int PostGroupDataModelId { get; set; }` property to the `PostDataModel` class? That way your model does not depend on the ability to create columns and you are explicit about your intentions

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That wouldn't stop EF from adding a shadow property along with the unnecessary foreign key.

Comment: Keep an eye out for calculated properties that have return values that have signatures which could be mistaken for ICollections of columns referenced by foreign keys - I've just spent over a day working through that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not the shadow property, but the fluent configuration:

```
e.HasOne<PostGroupDataModel>()
    .WithMany()
```

By using parameterless overloads you are effectively telling EF to create relationship with **no navigation properties** at both ends, which it does. However, you **do have** navigation properties, hence EF Core creates *another relationship* with conventional FK property/column name. Just because the default name `GroupId` is already reserved for your explicit relationship it appends number to it in order to make it unique.

The solution is to always use the `Has` / `With` overloads that represent the presense / absence of a navigation property. In your case:

```
e.HasOne(x => x.Group)
    .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
```

You can keep the rest of the fluent config, but since `GroupId` is the default value of the FK property/column in this case, `.HasForeignKey("GroupId")` can be skipped. Also because the `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` is the default for required relationships, `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` can be skipped too and the only remaining could be `.IsRequired()`. I.e.

```
.HasForeignKey("GroupId") // optional
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) // optional
.IsRequired();
```

Of course specifying them explicitly won't hurt.

Comment: Great answer. Appreciate that.